# A question about a possible interpretation of geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I've done the following reflection, but I don't know it it is correct or not:

Let $G=g_{ij}$ the metric tensor of a differentiable manifold $M$, then we could consider it as a map:
$G:TM\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ which for $p\in M$ and $v\in T_p$ associate $G(v)=g_{ij}v^iv^j$.

If we take the differential of $G$, $dG\in \Omega (TM)$, it is a differential form over $TM$, so in general it admits integral curves $\gamma_s(t):I\rightarrow TM$, parametrised by $s$.

So, for a given point of $M$ and its tangent vector, we could look for a $s$ such that  $\gamma_s$ passes for it. If we take the composition of $\gamma_s$ and the projection map $\pi:TT\rightarrow M$, we obtain a curve of $M$.

My question is: are these curves the geodesics?

Comment: What is an integral curve of a differential form?

Comment: You might want to look at the brief discussion of geodesic flow and geodesic spray [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic).